# SOQL Dynamic Query on objects ( Dynamic sobject name in soql )

Tags: dynamic-soql

```
String str = 'Order';

List<SObject> listData = [Select Id From str ];
```

Can we query like this, I want to query dynamically

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Try googling for "Apex dynamic SOQL". Or is there any specific problem you run into?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this

```
String str = 'Account';
String strQuery = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM '+str ;
system.debug(Database.query(strQuery));
```

In your case

```
String str = 'Order';
String strQuery = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM '+str ;
List<SObject> listData = Database.query(strQuery);
```