# Using a variable after FROM in SOQL statement

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-soql

I am building a custom VF component where I have an attribute which of type Object. I use this attribute to query first 10 records and display it using `pageblocktable`. The user can provide any object name like Account/contact/lead in the attribute and the first 10 records of that object gets displayed in a VF page.

I need some help on how I can use the variable name in the SELECT query after from. For example - [select field1 from variableName Limit 10]. Instead of a Sobject name I am giving a variable which has the Sobject name in it.

Below is my incomplete code, I am trying to make it dynamic. Right now I have used Accounts in my controller but I would like to use the variable - `controllerValue` where ever there is Account in my controller.

VF component:

```
apex:component controller="SampleComponentController" >

    <apex:attribute name="record" description="The type of record we are viewing."
                    type="Object" required="true" assignTo="{!controllerValue}"/>

    <apex:pageBlock title="Viewing {!record}">   

    </apex:pageBlock>

<apex:pageblock >
<apex:pageblocktable value="{!Records}" var="a">

<apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>

</apex:pageblocktable>
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:component>
```

VF component controller:

```
public class SampleComponentController {

public object controllerValue;

private ApexPages.StandardSetController setController{
        get {
            if(setController==NULL){
            system.debug('******Component***********' + controllerValue);
                List<account> accountList = [SELECT Name,BillingAddress,Phone FROM Account LIMIT 20];

// I would like the above query to be dynamic:
// List<controllerValue> accountList = [SELECT Name,BillingAddress,Phone FROM :controllerValue LIMIT 20];

                setController = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(accountList);

            }
            return setController;
        }
        set;
    }

    public List<Account> getRecords(){
        return (List<Account>) setController.getRecords();
    }

   public void setControllerValue (Object s) {
    controllerValue = s;
  }

  public Object getControllerValue() {
    return controllerValue;
  } 

}
```

I am planning to use it in VF Page as:

```
<apex:page controller="DynamicTableController">

<c:SampleComponent Record="Account"/>    

</apex:page>
```

I tried to use the dynamic query like:

```
List<account> accountList = Database.query('SELECT Name,BillingAddress,Phone FROM :controllerValue LIMIT 20');
```

I got this error when I saved the Visualforce Page :

```
Visualforce Error

System.QueryException: unexpected token: ':' 
Class.SampleComponentController.__sfdc_setController: line 9, column 1
Class.SampleComponentController.getRecords: line 21, column 1
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: you have to use Dynamic SOQL - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm

Comment: Yes I tried that = database.query('SELECT Name,BillingAddress,Phone FROM :controllerValue LIMIT 20'). I get - System.QueryException: unexpected token: ':'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to perform the cast, as you can just use dynamic Visualforce field binding. I wrote up this example just now that demonstrates the basic idea. This is more meant to be instructional than functional, but it does work in my developer org.

```
public class QueryAnyTableController {
    public String selectedType { get; set; }

    public SelectOption[] getObjectOptions() {
        SelectOption[] options = new SelectOption[0];
        for(SObjectType sobjType: Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values()) {
            DescribeSObjectResult describe = sobjType.getDescribe();
            options.add(new SelectOption(describe.getName(), describe.getLabel()));
        }
        return options;
    }
    public SObject[] getRecordList() {
        try {
            return Database.query('select Name'+(getAllowsOwner()?', OwnerId':'')+ ' FROM '+selectedType+' LIMIT 10');
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return new SObject[0];
        }
    }
    public Boolean getAllowsOwner() {
        try {
            return Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(selectedType).getDescribe().fields.getMap().containsKey('ownerid');
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<apex:page controller="QueryAnyTableController">
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                <apex:selectList value="{!selectedType}" size="1">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="form" />
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!objectOptions}" />
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!recordList}" var="rec">
                <apex:column value="{!rec['Id']}" />
                <apex:column value="{!rec['Name']}" />
                <apex:column rendered="{!allowsOwner}" value="{!rec['OwnerId']}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: N.B. I wouldn't put this in my production org, and neither should you. It requires quite a bit of work to be useful. This is only meant to be used as a getting started guideline.

Comment: Thanks much! I got an idea now on how to go about this. I am creating a reusable component such that if <c:SampleComponent Record="Account"/>  is used in any VF page then it will display the list of records of the object mentioned in Record=" ". I am planning to create a dynamic table where user can select the fields that they want to show in columns for any object. Do you think I am on right track in building this component?

Comment: @SfdcBat Yes, you can just use describes to determine which fields to use based on the object, and all without ever casting to a "concrete" sobject type. Feel free to play with this code as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks. Very much appreciated! I am planning to build something based on - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_sample_standard.htm ( like the screenshot at the bottom of the page in the link)

Comment: @SfdcBat Yeah, it shouldn't take more than a couple of hours to work out all the kinks. You're well on your way already.

Answer (score 2):

[SOQL Dynamic Query on objects ( Dynamic sobject name in soql )](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118656/soql-dynamic-query-on-objects-dynamic-sobject-name-in-soql) this is probably along the lines of what you're looking for, but you're going to query for an 'sobject' then cast the sobject to a specific type. You'll be running a query for:

```
List<sObject> listSObject = Database.query('select id, name, ownerId from ' + blah + 'where blah2');
List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
    if(blah == 'Account'){
        for(sObject genericRecord : listSObject)
            accList.add((Account)genericRecord);
    }
```

Comment: Nice!This is on the lines of what I am thinking but I would not know which type of List I have to create - List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();, It can be Contact/Lead or any custom object.

Comment: There's no need to cast each individual record to a new list; you can simply assign it to a specific type (it doesn't even require a cast!): `Sobject[] records = Database.query('select id, name, ownerid from '+objectName+' limit 10'); if(records.getSObjectType()==Account.SObjectType) { Account[] accounts = records; }`

Comment: Thanks, What happens if I have a custom object or Lead records that I is returned in the records? Do I need use if condition for each type of object?

Comment: @SfdcBat Check out my answer that demonstrates a very primitive "show any table" example.

Comment: My apologies, maybe I was mistaken or this is a recent addition but you don't need to parse the records individually. sfdcfox is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
database.query('SELECT Name,BillingAddress,Phone FROM' + controllerValue + 'LIMIT 20');
```

You need to consider preventing soql injection though. However, it doesn't mean you can't use String + variable in your dynamic SOQL at all.

Comment: This assumes that `controllerValue` is type `String`, which not the type in the OP's code. Also note that you will need to put spaces around the name of the object.

Comment: If controllerValue is a type of String , how can assign the result of the query which is a list of record with type Account/Contact/Lead(controllerValue type) ? I am trying to make it dynamic.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118656/soql-dynamic-query-on-objects-dynamic-sobject-name-in-soql this is probably along the lines of what you're looking for, but you're going to query for an 'sobject' then cast the sobject to a specific type.

Comment: @SfdcBat can you make it an SObject, not an object. In that way, we can probably easily walk around.

Comment: @LanceShi I should make the attribute of type String and the records which are returned should be of type Sobject. I took what sfdcfox gave as an answer and what you gave as an answer and combined it. I guess I got an idea now  on how to go about it.